# How to Restore Pip installation and its Installations in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python, python3

I messed up my Pip installation. There was one missing when I run `sudo apt-get install python-pip`. Then, I run after `sudo apt-get install python-dev`. Then, I started to get 404 errors in `ipython notebook`. So I did `sudo apt-get purge pip` and `sudo apt-get install pip`. Now, the problem is that all old installations of `pip` are there still.

After solving 6 packages' conflicts, I got the following error that I cannot resolve when running `ipython notebook`

```
...
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
ImportError: No module named notebook.notebookapp
```

I run `pip install notebook.notebookapp` but I get

```
Downloading/unpacking notebook.notebookapp
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement notebook.notebookapp
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for notebook.notebookapp
Storing debug log for failure in /home/masi/.pip/pip.log
```

I am not used to work with `virtualenv` but it may add here some benefits so please propose if you see it practical. I just want to run IPython-notebook to visualise my LaTeX notes and do some data-visualisation. I am not sure if Python 2 or 3 is more practical. System Python is 2 so probably isolation with `virtualenv` for Python 3 can be useful. However, not sure.

Choices

1. Clean install of Pip installation and its installations
2. Fix the ImportError of an individual package

---

How can you Restore Pip installation and its installations in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: The error message says the `backports.shutil_get_terminal_size` module is missing. So, how about just trying `pip install backports.shutil_get_terminal_size`?

Comment: @edwinksl Yes, thank you! Now, it doe s not work anymore `pip install full-name`. See the body.

Comment: Hmm, how about doing `pip install jupyter` as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/31459216/486919?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edwinksl's comment but with `sudo -H`

```
sudo -H pip install jupyter
```

where `jupyter` is the `notebook.notebookapp` application.